# Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym: How to write $\bigcup_n (A_n \cap B_n)$?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am learning measure theory and often it helps to know some (basic) set theory. For e.g. one can write union of measurable sets as a disjoint union and then use countable additivity of the measure.

I am reading the proof of special case of Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem from Folland:

We have two $\sigma$-finite measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $X$ and the space $X$ is written as $X=\cup_n E_n=\cup_n F_n$ of increasing union with both $\mu(E_n)$ and $\nu(F_n)$ finite for all $n$. From here, we want to write $X=\cup_n X_n$ where $X_n$ are disjoint with both $\mu(X_n)$ and $\nu(X_n)$ finite for all $n$

I think $X_n= (E_n\cap F_n)\cap {G_n}^c$, where $G_n=(\cup_{k=1}^{n-1} (E_k \cap F_k))$. Clearly $X_n $ are disjoint. But how do I show that $\cup_n X_n=X$?

In general, what is $\cup_n (A_n \cap B_n)$?

Comment: To answer your question in the title, you can generally use DeMorgan's law to get $$\left(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n\cap B_n)\right)^c = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(A_n^c \cup B_n^c)$$

Comment: For the question in the body I would suggest defining the sets $D_n = E_n \setminus (E_1 \cup ... \cup E_{n-1})$, which are disjoint for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, and then note $X=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} D_n$.  Now you can refine the $D_n$s with respect to the $F_n$s if you want. You can even make sets $X_{n,m}$ if you want. Your existing approach does not work since, what happens when $E_n\cap F_n=\phi$ for all $n$?  It does not capture the set $X$ that you want. So under your attempt we may have $\cup_n X_n \neq X$.

Comment: @Michael Since $\cup_n E_n=\cup_n F_n=X$ and they are increasing, I don't think we can have $E_n \cap F_n=\phi$ for all $n$

Comment: What is meant by “and they are increasing”? Your problem description seems to use any sets $E_n$, for which the union $\cup_{i=1}^nE_i$ clearly defines sets that grow with $n$ and hence is an “increasing union.”

Comment: @Michael I just mean that since both $E_n$ and $F_n$ grow with $n$ and cover the whole space, they must intersect for all (possibly large) $n$

Comment: Then it sounds like you also want the $E_n$ and $F_n$ sets themselves to be increasing with $n$ (that is , nondecreasing). In that case the problem is simpler and you can show your existing union is $X$ by fixing $x\in X$ and observing there must be an integer $n$ for which $x\in E_k$ for all $k\geq n$.